# How many people are known to have had a mutual positive relationship with Snape?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

Snape is usually perceived as a tragic, unfriendly loner with Lily being the only nice person in his whole life.

But though as unlikable as he was, he still was intelligent and brave and hard working, worthy of some respect among those who knew him well and craving for social acceptance. Is it possible he never met people willing to sincerely befriend him or establish some emotional relationships?

I would put his **mother** on the list first but that is an assumption.  He took her name (Prince) suggesting he wanted to associate with her. Also the fact that he knew loads of information about Hogwarts leads us to conclusion that his mother spent a lot of time with him explaining about wizarding world. And his decision to be in Slytherin is probably due to his mother attending there.

Also it is possible that his relationships with **Lucius** were sincerely friendly, unlike with other Death Eaters. [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195595/snapes-curious-reaction-in-the-goblet-of-fire) gives a really good picture of it. It also looks like **Narcissa** respected him greatly and possibly also considered herself Snape's friend.

**Dumbledore?** I would not call their relationship "friendship", but Snape shared a lot of his inner feelings with Dumbledore, so I guess they established some connection of mutual respect at least.

**Are there any canon indications in the books about people who have established  friendly, emotional (in a positive way) relationships with Snape?**

I'm looking for mutual feelings, not something like Slytherins respecting their teacher.

Comment: Didn't expect it to be such a controversial question, hanging on the edge. Poor Snape seems to be denied any friends :\

Comment: Who's voting to close this, and why?

Comment: Is this possible to answer canonically?

Comment: @VogonPoet Why not?

Comment: other than what we see with Lily Potter, I don't think there is much canon evidence to answer this objectively